# Adventure Mode strange bug

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I'm in Adventure Mode, I can't destroy or place blocks when using the right tool. Is this change an update?

Answer (score 0):

From the [wiki on Adventure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Adventure):

> In this mode, the player cannot directly destroy any blocks with any tools or place any blocks, in order to avoid spoiling adventure maps or griefing servers.

And:

> - Blocks cannot be destroyed by hand, and require an item with the CanDestroy tag.
> - Blocks require the CanPlaceOn tag to be placed.

These tags were added in version 1.8.

---

Here is a command to give you a diamond shovel which can break grass blocks:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:grass"]}
```

Here is a command to give you a diamond pickaxe which can break stone blocks:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

Here is a command to give you a grass block which can break grass blocks and/or be placed on grass blocks:

```
/give @p minecraft:grass 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass"],CanDestroy:["minecraft:grass"]}
```